# Restore Bacula Files

Tags: database, restore, data-recovery, bacula

Q1: Can I restore bacula files to another location? Because whenever I restore my bacula files, it goes directly to the client on which the files was backed up.

Q2: Can I restore bacula files if ever the bacula server and client crashed?

Thanks.

Comment: There is actually a guide for this: http://www.technowut.com/2012/07/23/how-to-do-a-restore-using-bacula/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1: The client used for restoring is defined in the restore job, so you could just add another restore job or alter the configuration to fit your need.

Q2: Yes. The best option is to create bootstrap files during your backup, which can be used to restore in the absence of the database. If you don't have even that, you can use the **bscan**  program to scan your tapes and recreate a database. Beware though, this process takes a lot of time, and according to the bacula docs, is somewhat inexact.

I would suggest establishing some bare metal recovery system that allows you to quickly recover from an incident concerning your backup server, maybe in form of a Rescue CD with a statically linked Bacula version on it, as suggested by the documentation.

You'll find details for all of this in the manuals.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question SvenW. For my 1st question, I am worried that if ever the client crashed, where can I restore my files. Since everytime I do restore on bconsole, it restores the files on the client. this is my configuration on my bacula-director                                                         Job {
  Name = "RestoreFiles"
  Type = Restore
  Client=local-fd
  FileSet="Full Set"
  Storage = File
  Pool = Default
  Messages = Standard
  Where = /tmp/bacula-restores
}

Comment: Please disregard my comment above to SvenW. I found out that doing the restore command on bacula console (bconsole) you can change some parameters like where to restore the files by entering the command "mod" when asked "Ok to run?(yes/mod/no)". Anyway thanks again for answering my question SvenW. =)